# How to get values comma separated from tag name in XML Document

Tags: c#, xml

I have a Xml document with below format,

```
<Fields>
        <Field Name="A">
          <DataField>A</DataField>
          <Value>"AA"</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="B">
          <DataField>B</DataField>
          <Value>"BB"</Value>
        </Field>
</Fields>
```

I just want to obtain the Values of  Tag as Comma Separated, e.g. AA,BB,..etc.

I tried this:

```
xmlFile.Root.Elements("Fields").Elements("Field").Elements("Value");
```

but could not achieve ,Any suggestions?

Comment: Your value field is wrong: `<Value>"AA"></Value>`, it has an extra `>`. For both AA and BB.

Comment: It was a typo mistake

Comment: Desired output includes " or without? ( "AA","BB" or AA,BB ?)

Comment: I just need them as comma separated.

Comment: "It was a typo mistake" - fixed it for you.

Comment: Does the xml always look like this or can `<Value>` tags appear in other places too? In that case it would be important to consider only Fields/Field/Value explicitly ...

Answer (score 2):

The code you've got already retrieves a sequence of elements, although your root element *is* `Fields`, so you shouldn't select `Fields` *from* the root. After that, you just need to join the values of those elements together. I'd use `string.Join` for that:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var values = doc.Root
            .Elements("Field")
            .Elements("Value")
            .Select(x => x.Value);
        string joined = string.Join(",", values);
        Console.WriteLine(joined);
    }
}
```

(Samvel's approach of using `Aggregate` for the joining works perfectly well too, but I find `string.Join` simpler to understand. It would also be more efficient for a large number of elements, but that's probably irrelevant, and could be fixed by using a `StringBuilder` if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your xml a little:

```
<Fields>
    <Field Name="A">
      <DataField>A</DataField>
      <Value>AA</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="B">
      <DataField>B</DataField>
      <Value>BB</Value>
    </Field>
</Fields>
```

Here is short example how you can achieve this using [Linq to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.xml"))
            {
                XDocument document = XDocument.Load(tr);
                var allDescendants = document.Descendants("Value");
                Console.WriteLine(allDescendants.Select(x=>x.Value).Aggregate((x,y)=> x+","+y));
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a `StreamReader`?

Comment: Doing `.Aggregate((x,y)=> x+","+y)` is awful string concatenation - if the document is large this can be a terrible way to build a string from a performance POV.

Comment: @Enigmativity Shouldn't that be addressed when it becomes a problem? I'd say it's premature optimization if the solution is readable and works as intended. (Not saying you're wrong ... )

Comment: @Fildor - I think there are certain things that we know to avoid and should make a habit of doing so. Especially when `values.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "," + y)` can be replaced with `String.Join(",", values)` - a more succinct and performant method.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hm, yes. I think I can agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `XmlDocument` and a bit of `XPath`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.LoadXml("<Fields>" +
              "<Field Name='A'>" +
                "<DataField>A</DataField>" +
                "<Value>'AA'</Value>" +
                "</Field>" +
              "<Field Name='B'>" +
                "<DataField>B</DataField>" +
                "<Value>'BB'</Value>" +
              "</Field>" +
            "</Fields>");

String result = string.empty;

XmlNodeList values = doc.SelectNodes("Fields/Field/Value");   //using Xpath

  foreach (XmlNode node in values)
  {
     result +=  node.InnerText + "," ;       
  }

result = result.TrimEnd(',');
```